# Mongo Template Difference between days and compare with db field

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, date, mongotemplate

I have document in db like below manner, I wish to subtract the current date, get difference in days and compare the difference with value stored in db as validity in same document.

So my query should fetch all the documents whose `startDate` and current date difference is greater than validity

```
//mongo document snap
{
  "campaignDuration": {         
    "startDate": {
      "$date": "2021-10-21T11:39:59.657Z"
    },
  },
  "attributes":{
    "validity":2
  }
}
```

Can someone help me with the query in spring using mongo template

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
   {
      $match: {
         $expr: {
            $gte: [
               {
                  $dateDiff: {
                     startDate: "$$NOW",
                     endDate: "$startDate",
                     unit: "day"
                  }
               },
               "$attributes.validity"
            ]
         }
      }
   }
])
```

`$dateDiff` was newly introduced in MongoDB version 5.0. If you run an older version then replace the expression by `{$multiply: [{$subtract: ["$startDate", "$$NOW"]}, 1000*60*60*24]}`

Comment: I'm new to mongo can you help me with spring mongo template equivalent of above

Comment: Sorry, I am not familiar with Java or spring

Answer (score 0):

I wrote spring mongo template base on Wernfried Domscheit's answer above (https://stackoverflow.com/a/69632053/7009165)

```java
AggregationOperation matchOperation = (context) -> {
            Document matchDocument = new Document("$expr", new Document("$gte",
                    Arrays.asList(
                            new Document("$dateDiff", new Document()
                                    .append("startDate", "$$NOW")
                                    .append("endDate", "$startDate")
                                    .append("unit", "day")),
                            "$attributes.validity"
                    )));
            return new Document("$match", matchDocument);
        };
mongoTemplate.aggregate(Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation), "collection", OutputClass.class);
```